# How do I target an error as result of timeout in python

Tags: python, timeout, web.py

I am writing a function to restart my code whenever there is a connection problem.

whenever I disconnect my WiFi, the following is generated.

> File "C:\Users\m2jto\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 174, in _new_conn
> conn = connection.create_connection(
> File "C:\Users\m2jto\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\connection.py", line 72, in create_connection
> for res in socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, socket.SOCK_STREAM):
> File "C:\Users\m2jto\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\socket.py", line 955, in getaddrinfo
> for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
> socket.gaierror: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\Users\m2jto\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 703, in urlopen
> httplib_response = self._make_request(
> File "C:\Users\m2jto\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 386, in _make_request
> self._validate_conn(conn)
> File "C:\Users\m2jto\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 1040, in _validate_conn
> conn.connect()
> File "C:\Users\m2jto\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 358, in connect
> conn = self._new_conn()
> File "C:\Users\m2jto\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 186, in _new_conn
> raise NewConnectionError(
> urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x000002D25A1416F0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\Users\m2jto\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 440, in send
> resp = conn.urlopen(
> File "C:\Users\m2jto\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 785, in urlopen
> retries = retries.increment(
> File "C:\Users\m2jto\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\retry.py", line 592, in increment
> raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
> urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='bsc-dataseed.binance.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x000002D25A1416F0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "c:\Users\m2jto\OneDrive\Desktop\customers\cus2\transferFrom.py", line 23, in 
> balance_wei=web3.eth.get_balance(address1)
> File "C:\Users\m2jto\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\web3\module.py", line 57, in caller
> result = w3.manager.request_blocking(method_str,
> File "C:\Users\m2jto\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\web3\manager.py", line 197, in request_blocking
> response = self._make_request(method, params)
> File "C:\Users\m2jto\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\web3\manager.py", line 150, in _make_request
> return request_func(method, params)
> File "C:\Users\m2jto\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\web3\middleware\formatting.py", line 94, in middleware
> response = make_request(method, params)
> File "C:\Users\m2jto\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\web3\middleware\gas_price_strategy.py", line 90, in middleware
> return make_request(method, params)
> File "C:\Users\m2jto\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\web3\middleware\formatting.py", line 94, in middleware
> response = make_request(method, params)
> File "C:\Users\m2jto\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\web3\middleware\attrdict.py", line 33, in middleware
> response = make_request(method, params)
> File "C:\Users\m2jto\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\web3\middleware\formatting.py", line 94, in middleware
> response = make_request(method, params)
> File "C:\Users\m2jto\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\web3\middleware\formatting.py", line 94, in middleware
> response = make_request(method, params)
> File "C:\Users\m2jto\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\web3\middleware\formatting.py", line 94, in middleware
> response = make_request(method, params)
> File "C:\Users\m2jto\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\web3\middleware\buffered_gas_estimate.py", line 40, in middleware
> return make_request(method, params)
> File "C:\Users\m2jto\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\web3\middleware\exception_retry_request.py", line 105, in middleware
> return make_request(method, params)
> File "C:\Users\m2jto\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\web3\providers\rpc.py", line 88, in make_request
> raw_response = make_post_request(
> File "C:\Users\m2jto\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\web3_utils\request.py", line 48, in make_post_request
> response = session.post(endpoint_uri, data=data, *args, **kwargs)  # type: ignore
> File "C:\Users\m2jto\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 577, in post
> return self.request('POST', url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
> File "C:\Users\m2jto\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 529, in request
> resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
> File "C:\Users\m2jto\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 645, in send
> r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
> File "C:\Users\m2jto\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 519, in send
> raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
> requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='bsc-dataseed.binance.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x000002D25A1416F0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed'))

How do I target this error so I can use except block to restart my code?

```
  except:
      restart()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can catch a generic exception with:

```
except Exception as e:
     print(f"Exception has been raised: {e}")
     restart()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to catch a specific exception, you can specify it in `except`:

```
except socket.gaierror:
    restart()
```